# Erlang concurrent programming

Tags: concurrency, erlang

Write an Erlang function named calculator that takes no arguments. The function, when run in a process, should wait to receive a message. If the message is in the form of a tuple of four items: `{ Pid, Operand, X, Y }`, do this:

- If Operand is add, send a message to Pid with the result of adding X and Y.
- If Operand is subtract, send a message to Pid with the result of subtracting Y from X.
- If Operand is multiply, send a message to Pid with the result of multiplying X and Y.
- If Operand is divide, send a message to Pid with the result of dividing X by Y.

Then, rerun the function.

- If the message is in the form of a tuple with two items: { Pid, terminate }, then send a message to Pid of done. Do not rerun the function.
- If the message is of any other form, ignore it and rerun the function.

My code:

```
calculate() ->
  receive
    {Pid, Operand, X, Y} 
      if 
         Operand == "add" -> Pid ! X+Y
         Operand == "substract" -> Pid ! Y - X
         Operand == "multiply" -> Pid ! X*Y
         Operand == "divide" -> Pid ! X/Y
    {Pid, terminate} -> Pid ! "done"
    _ -> calculate();
  end.
```

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: You should look at the help for edit and format your question in a more friendly way.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not compile, you should have a look at the basic erlang syntax first.

I give you some clues:

you should not use the `if` statement for your problem but use pattern matching instead like in

```
receive
    {From,add,X,Y} ->
        From ! X+Y,
        calculate();
    {From,sub,X,Y} -> 
    ...
```

Generally, for this purpose, use atoms like `add` rather than string like `"add"`

you should have a function to start the function `calculate/0` in a separate process:

```
start() ->
    spawn(fun() -> calculate() end).
```